# CMS restriction in ASM spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, restriction, spartacus-storefront

Am working on spartacus, I have a CMSLinkComponent which is having restrictions with user group, lets take admingroup, when i try to impersonate the user who is having admingroup, am unable to see the CMSLinkComponent. I heard that this is an limitation in the spartacus(https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/asm/)

Is there any other way to achieve this in spartacus.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly point out, it is not possible for the AS Agent to apply the customer restriction rules for CMS when impersonating a customer.

The CMS will react according to the authenticated user. In the case of ASM impersonation, the user is the Assisted Service Agent.

As a workaround, perhaps you can evaluate if it is worth giving the AS Agent some additional groups if it makes sense for your use case (and if it even works as intended with the CMS).  But there are  downsides to this. During customer impersonation, the CMS will always behave according to the CS Agent's groups, regardless or which customer is impersonated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can we customize the endpoints to pass impersonated user id instead of logged user id ..